# Creating a SQL View where columns are data from another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I am developping a simple criminal records management system using SQL Server.

I have the following tables:

```
Criminal (
          CriminalID,
          Gender ...)

Victim (
        VictimID,
        Gender ...)

Crime(
       CrimeID, 
       CriminalID,
       VictimID ...)
```

I am interested in creating a view that gives us a simple statistic about Gender of victims by gender of criminals.

Example of wanted output:

```
Victim \ Criminal | Male | Female

Male              |  4   | 2

Female            |   8  | 5
```

Grouping the Number of crimes only by gender of victims or only by gender of criminals isnt hard , But how can i perform this task ? How to Expand the Gender of criminals into 2 separate columns and perform the needed task ?

Comment: add some subquery columns

Answer (score 1):

You need a conditional sum:

```
select criminal.gender
  ,SUM(case when victim.gender = 'M' then 1 else 0 end) as "Male"
  ,SUM(case when victim.gender = 'F' then 1 else 0 end) as "Female"
from ...
group by criminal.gender
```

The `CASE` returns either 1 or 0...

Comment: Thank you so much sir it worked
I have a little question : can we expand the same query in the case the values of the second column are multiple ? i mean in this case it was possible since the values that gender can take is known ; is there a way we do the same operation in case for example for age (where we may have wide range of possible values that age can take) ?

Comment: @user3179490: You need to know the actual values for age and then it's  `SUM(case when age between 18 and 25 then 1 else 0 end)`. You might also look at the `PIVOT` functionality in SQL Server.